# Display all network interfaces on Solaris

Tags: networking, solaris, ethernet

On Linux, the command `mii-tool` displays the list of Ethernet interfaces and other information. What equivalent command existson Solaris? My goal is to view all LAN networks that my Solaris machine is connected to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Solaris 11:

```
dladm show-phys
```

On older releases:

```
kstat -c net ":::link*"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Solaris 10 OS:

```
dladm show-link
```

Answer (score -1):

#### For Solaris 10 OS:

**Show link status**:

```
dladm show-dev
```

**Show device information**:

```
dladm show-link
```